# cumulative layout shift and jquery

Tags: jquery, lighthouse, core-web-vitals

I am using materialize css 0.100.2 and have been looking into CLS on my website I have identified the problem as being this piece of code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
      $('.lt-slider').height($(window).height() + 15).css('position', 'relative');
  });
```

With this code in place my CLS is 1.13 if I remove it 0.039 but I loose a chunk of the screen so that the content disappears behind the slider is there a solution to keep the content and reduce the CLS.

Comment: Do you have the HTML code so that I can inspect what is happening you should make space on the parent for this rersize I think

Comment: there is a lot of html code it may be easier if I give you the link to the website [link](https://drift-in.co.uk)

Answer (score 2):

I found this posted by gerald:

First, create a class "antiCls" and add it to your custom CSS (in the HEAD element) as follows:

```
.antiCls { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

then use this bit of javascript:

```
var cls = document.getElementsByClassName('antiCls'),
    i = cls.length;
    
for (i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
    cls[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
```

then I added the class to every element that was affected by "Avoid large layout shifts" in lighthouse you may need to test each element applied the antiCls class to but it worked

Comment: I used a similar non-JS approach based off this answer, the header draws just fine and produces no CLS although the main sadly does (without really showing the shift or the shift being visible to the user) so I was at a bit of a dead end, I set the visibility hidden on the biggest CLS cause via an inline style then I set it back to visible at the __end__ of the large non-critical CSS. Went from a CLS of 1.8 in Lighthouse to a score of 0.021

Answer (score 1):

I have been digging a little deeper into my problem an as far as I can tell it is to do with Materialize CSS and jquery version. I have tried .097 0.100.2 and 1.00 all with the same results the CLS is 0.4 if I use jquery 2.2.4 but if I use jquery 3 and above the CLS shoots up to 1.4 but if I use materialize CSS version 1 and use javascript the CLS drops and I can use the above to reduce to 0